# vega-lite tick z-index when there is occlusion?

Tags: vega-lite

In a visualization I have I want to order the marks when there is occlusion (based on an attribute of the mark). I tried using opacity, but I would prefer being able to directly control which element is laid on top. I checked out the doc and saw some discussions https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/1684, but cannot locate if there is a way to directly do this. Or if I can creatively use layers to achieve the same result?

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgYATgGtsYYJDwBPQsn1HG8PaqjwJhfQEYAvuoiQA7owAmLfQCcAAxB7lDISvDcPoxK1PqgEB4AHgkaSVAAZozIYj4WWrnoeIxUACqMqMgAIoyZmWrpSUam5jiQAI6s6EoleMWl5mEZkOjJjLAJlnhibWBBLk1uTZDGaRke2bn57WLc1NTIWgCS+cPNJmYW3FoxSuhijRtQYxNTfbP6oVAl1pM430gYnQ7Fy-3miwyyxGUT2WnWG0gWzyFnQ8BKygAwoh0Fo8E9EZc5pAlNxULEHgSRggHnNEs8oD4yehYvoANpNZ6QBBabhiR7nLlRHzIMB4bhgWJ4I5ojEqQWI4VDTmIqUy9E8JRiiVKqkM7m5ZAa5R6rnaHRMzzylUjViMMBRXq8x42sAAXQVHi0PUO7NdHgk1Hw1G9a09zQAxD4AGwAJgA7LGABymxER+rxzJBZUMyNOTLx+PsaSpkYRpxFo0NcMeCMBaTRotnf1QCPseDsHyx2OQV1ulWQpLQ5rcQho5hrHD0kbInYvY1KbG4-EKlpXdqk8n3AUq7nwWkIrlMjCsnAc3MeJXayW9dVy0vNXU1qBq70L69PlsG2YLh8ec2WtaF5QHaDrKHgzp-lAPJ8i6uYeq6kDenEcxsk4thBHQACstjoWAeEERhdBBE4-bPIOECDsOkCOtk8RTpY1jvIgVg6EoyCwOCTgLNRPjFJgU4rBQDysBxfrPNOiKypqS54hYn65kC+yHCcc6QMgyRmFolQRHgAD6TgBHpyDCWIemgrohrGHphB8lYOb6oUwIlOUOm1PUXzERWIQ+b5QRYQmWEDgqkkjNJWI4nJ7QwfyD5KQcRynBYGlaTpvQGUZJkPOZRw6FZNl2fADlck5AyuVU7kNDg3Z0PG9Z+X5ATRsFKqhc04WLpF+LRfAzo7opewJapyWaUcaX6YZxmmTllmzNZtkSEVcWlS5yAVBVdRVWAsbRnQADM8bRgEx0nadWF7S1EmIR1snddBvWwXFg0qUl7QpWNVTpZNWVmRZeVzQVi3FYiK2DOtNSbfoDZ0PWsanfDARJtIl0bG1Hg3V1Fgxf1+rPYlanvdpn0TZl01-flC32ctRSreDlX6OddDSLGWEI6dF3kSF10LrdFgAdwVpPcp+MjalxMZVN2XkwDlNLeGSE02DbmQzgWFYXQFaxg1vksyjGRo-Ocq8z1fVC0Nr3hKNRO6RLP0zf9yDzYVwMjKD5UQx5qu7Yd8baz5QWc613NG5jJuPfLePDW9VvjbbZO5RTzvU85SsbZ7YDRk4dDRg2bMnXtAcbMO+vBzJof3abEfC1Hltizb33x7NjuA1T8tu2tyvpzn2eZ37ITNYHV2KRjy5Yw9sVV+bBMx+LDdSwnMtJ23ivu-TOCNj3e19yRetJAbow8+Xe6V4hkcW+pM-16T89N07QPJ2VHdp1tvt0Em0ZJnnx1OLvED7yPUVNC4gtALICuNq7n0JrHOev0F7N1li7Zo7c6YqzAImDWyYv4BF-gYUuEVR5hwnqfCB0865fWvrA2+Lc5aIWQZ3F+shoxBDql-QuUIubD0PgQiu4diFT1Fh9K+ktKEOzvq3WhK8n4exfvGWqQQ4Zf3jDg-+XDAE0WiIggMJCBHW3IcI+2id77LxTqvVBdUmZJkMoo5ReDOrcMgK+DqH4NFmxeqQwRei7bS3gUvCRJipFrzQQEbO3Zt5KMHqjWxxseFEIGto6OZCSb6O8WImhik6HP30EmdWTgnDSG3hzIuHD9QALut+I095J5uJ0dAihBjF5GL8Y-FB6cAiyICE4LWfdCnsKDpwkO9jsauJFgkjxSSvFwNSZoqAGTpGBCTMRBR1iIkl36WXQZhpfxVJGbXMZccb6iOodMhW-iWlbW4rIZhW8+7YJWXvKJR8hnbJrhfRJ+yRGGPEekyRZznBBFkHtAu29kZ3L-g8wZ48cZcjPu43R4zG6HIQQ-Wm9C-nBLYUOYpXJSkWFAo6CCfJhkvKgbPOpKSjnItTnMnAuTYx0C1ntLBGLKJYqkqospTy+HVNGXC959SfGNO+ac1FNLOlvycEw7pNi1n4LUXi8CkFnmQMvp4hFny0mOR+SK-CTh1b1mkFgkFRS+klPZbi+0+LFVcp2a8vZMD+VTMpaY9OuTglwyCIa6VpqBlqM5XE-hPLanJMmRS4xzTtWdKzvGZmnrQW4JlXY31kKiXKrefa8lSKw0osyTS5Mb9slYPCcaoe3r1lJpPv67luzeXppDZmpp2bqX4T2lnYI1y-axi9dis1hCoWIhhTU0lwaqH1qFeGnNzaFlJhZtvZlYBi73ITdE4+vDK02pJUIiZI7fFjsbYEvJrbGx9x-nGlRPqOXJqVbCoNW7EU7s1cKideT1ZBEbFgpMXa2XnrHhW8BAbq03rVQ0r5D7x1NryQsg6R1WGfrCj2mJfaRgDsDUO296rjmzP3VhKNWFfZ9wHsWyJS6j4KT-VW21NayV1vvSVLVT6Ar0qCIymDp7wXltXWR9dKr4UHPQ06gJqCJV0uZj0zFJru3ft7Sm69qGgMCpA7Rx94H4x7SZpKvuRreklok2Wi9v7oXxIA7J3jwGNWKbA-u8xWEGyztg+1eDK7YmceJdxvlGaaMgzo+B7J2EVPHrs+jBzfrnOprtVR7dgrQN7sE5-LyzG84BcNrpn9HGDP-oo4Bkz8mzOeaU-ugIqnjrxbZiewjqzS2yr06l-thmMvGY+aZjDXnAldPpYygpiWD6SbsC4q9g7N1ycdVmqlLXmH7T2vk-DnWcVSb6yhgbWWhsNpG6grWCzX1YPrNNoLl7rUubTeFu9kXzPRfTrGMV0hOkddY8RiF+mavpY3aqxboblvOq2ud2R8i8N+002J7TX7kvtFI2l8jT2eMNey01vLq2nDrdw9vTtN2KuJqq050HXGDvDqOwp3LFnVvnewiEd923uvqJFNJ-rz3IdLd3Sts7LM2ula00RlHy7gsY-22F7HfHhvvf0N2PV7a-YEZZ+VnTlWUvo4e2D1ztaIu49ds11bW9iLSA-cjiXqP5K9b26FyjPPGv8d+dVVXgLhcNQ12VxdbPHm7bXVzg3aGjd84E2d6Qqn8kGuWdbsFt32PS6Q7V8HbnqPHbx6dj70hZHYaTNd338bbd3eq0Hx7cvDu87e27j72HiIBC6drZn-3Wda-Z-bkLMmFs09e3T-n1U1b0sRqToHCHKfzepw6mvUX6cfcztnCVzfJezb15Xjv7nw9K5h2dw6+1smD+18D3XDv9eZer6O7vdftpWaCHHjT8+y-3dT7LrHzuofG+1cmTChlisI1F8X8XgOh+t7m0Zqvnf18nZ7wLpMqno03-hvvnbofs0Mhq-mPmHorkgsrmdkmDHkjgnmei3o5ohiAcHunobmfq7ibttB0nIt7glpro-gvj1hTi-nVm-uPpAV6NAR9rgYdEsmzIAcnoHqgWnifoNl3p-pvnDF9gdPHmLjbqXkASnqwcftzqfrThvtnvoFvLIO6rGggWxmUiDjLpjuIRwR-hHl-jgFvDHvGFhLZoQXBmThzqoY7qvu-h5pPvjunFvAsrqtBgQYof7mjigVomweoS9podYZHjIWKrkhbn5HfiyuJkQQfiIe4WIU7hoVYVAVPltHtFrDDFbgIX7kngHm4VAKAeQeAQrjlj4doWAIkZchNv5kYfZiYeXpzivvVpYRPnETYQkQmBrDvlgkwRkW3mARDnUVQTMjQTIarhWPgWzHOgumkUIfYioUfmodEV4bEdQfEQMaprqrvoXqJiEQDsYUgaYdMeYbUZQfkQ0b4ToXtAsgEOdO0coUvhXlTt0QcdDo0QMWcdkmUc4ekVcaQSPrcaHnkQ8ccUUfkhrIkdvMEfOqylsU-sgZ0TkXcRAYcQsY8ToZdjDAVm0eUYFmTvzILGQSHvLjjvCX0YsToX3i2h6l-JcVLpkfFFERYfcefhOntH3gFOptrEWqkYnhMR0TiegRIZwVoZvoybIGrIET5EXhsSXmEcISwZETMbSXCX8YUXwRrD-oWhScPsvqPrCb8fSU2lBjDBWGiW8Zya4dCbiRni7lntgacZhEwgXg1GKWCaERCcQVCdyewXMfUQif8acerDnO+qCWMRyZKcwVSdkWaRgZIVwdITocdMRPGNxH7Hkmqc-l8e3lqfiQqZvvknSoWAwQjAOE0GRPOiAC4EAA) You can see that my ticks are overlapping, and I want to make the gray one ("scroll") have a lower z-index than every other mark. Right now I am using opacity, but it's still occlusion that I like to avoid.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the z-index using the `order` encoding, however it only accepts sort = "ascending" or "descending", which doesn't directly help you here.

You can get around this limitation by using a calculate transform to define the particular z-order you want:

```
"transform": [
  {"calculate": "datum.actionChart == 'scroll' ? 0 : 1", "as": "zorder"}
]
```

And then reference that new field in the order encoding:

```
"encoding": {
  ...
  "order": {"field": "zorder", "type": "quantitative"}
}
```

The result looks like this ([Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgYATgGtsYYJDwBPQsn1HG8PaqjwJhfQEZbkboXTxmx5wF91EEZa6EqwAGbcWqj6ANoaEIbw6GLwrGLoeOY4kAAmGayodJ54PEoAwojoWnhgALy1YADkCFrcYmKNYAD8YAAMYDhOalDosBYAXpE5yFqQvhoAugFQAO6MOSz6AJy9vcuQyErw3DmMStT6oBCBAB6X8deQYYzIYjkWWq8ZjFQAKoyoZAAEUYYTCagegRMZgsAEdWCESnhvlQIddHugbowxjhDEixFk+vN0f4HpAfLjIVBnq93tkxNxqNQZgBJd7LdFGUyEtxaU5KZJo9EjLE4gyWPAE-R7KAlaximWQdLsV4K4nXUmc44M2aU4XUl5vCzFUoVKp4IWc6E8pTcVBnQUcx4IZKEq76qA5O3oM6xKmclptMSWj2QY7TMB4bhgM6ZYLwErKEP6sMncxOlOxmYm5SR6Ph9P+52vZAJ0rJ4WQbQ6L0rFQZyusRhgY5KPCtYNFpZFyDBc6EuIex4Saj4ajBHwNzkAYhyADYAEwAdgXAA4KzOwUuwr1C0PAtOnGEl0v2NIN49D6fS+Cp5ettI56f2UWD+x4OwcguF5Au1T1RAmqPFMMyXE8hp0lAkx8qBrjWnCCJtswKLmOqQGpkozwXLiljWGBLBWDoSjILAYpOL0vjoXkyL3JyFDJKwJF+vq7opjm5SVNUFgFheSqMsyWhshYyA3GYWgAoceAAPpOFsUnIPRYhSSquglsYUmEG0Vh7qGnzpCUfwSSCYLSnQvROEuuxWdZvQAKzLrZ-4NqxlbsWaXHZIG7S8QyTKspBByiTMEltjJckKckykzDoakaVp8A6Smekof8gLGeCODfnQS4PjZNlbHOTlUi5nJuZxFqefAHbBnefF+YJAUiWJIXSbJ8mKVFqkEupmkSAlvHJQZyCpcCoIZWAC5znQADMS5zlsC2LUttnTUVLE9mV5oWF5NU9r5AlCdkTXBYCoVtRFSkqTF3VxX1iWVoNPzDUZY36I+dAPguS3fVsq7SGtwolRiZbKO5FVQDtPn8f5wlBeJp2teFHVXbFvXaQNXxDSN6X6CtdDSAutk-Utq36kB6JA4Em0eZoVQ1twdZQ-Vh1QMd8OSWF7WRSjN1o-1tWPYZaWvTgtm2XQFkLnl1mEwDFMbSDHFbZV1VMwdjVwy1nMXZ113ID18X3ZygvPcLJmi1Nc2WdLuyOWTzkK4mSs05AkO1ftMNHZrCPa8j0Wo4bGP6U92Mi2Ac5OHQc6PsTi3TXbwrk9clMjIrYPbVVQZq57rPexz51+11+u3ejAuYyHL3m+HshzhHNu7IV9vFY7prlRnqvu9DDWw81PsF9z-u84HZfB0Lo1V0+UdztN9fmXLyct6Dbcq1nnfMxrvf50jA9Fwbd1ByllfjZZdCrnOq6xwtTjzwki-O+DVZ07W9Z7V3LOBZvZ3b5dg-F3zRuPBNqHKuK4JZrkvlsG+Bg77pxXt5Ne6se4nS3lzH+u8S78x7EAo++glw116DlS+CcSQOyHJAamD83av3Xkg9mX9UG6wDvvEeh8zbHyXNlXoX1L5LigSnchadl52DTNnbuXtP6IwYTzP+w8sHlzHjjHAOV8arlkjwvhMChGQCzPGJ2eYWwiIQTnD+yD6E62kXvUucjR6m3HsfLYUdvyz14U3daZCKHt1XtQxB4jTGSPMb-SxmCyHYLYfoVc4snBOGkLPUmidSGhg8Z5EsitRHvzZlrfuaC9ZBIAYEUJdjtgcK2E4KW9c4kkObu4wRysIaZ3gd44xGS+7f0YUPZh1jWGFJwL9My3D1GuMBpo2prsUlOzSRvPxvsd45IwXkqABTFFgHIrIAhM966QMGfLapTtYF1I7o0sRucJHTOyUwqxIT5G2KWSsma8dZ7-S2QvHZrcRlULIR7I5Ji6H+MLrM-+B8sY4MGL0BxxCNQJLYjUl2TYDFtg7BM2hmTWkWLmYCiuYTBilLoFLaaEDwWAUha5aFlD6m7Q+W-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-Yatjp6ONLmmvjDlDygPAwfYJ8dz7J34ag++uln6pPfqrhZMFj5+1KapiB-ZQn1MiaYzOtt9Kv0LqlREugKHK15TXRh7Zm7R2gbw-uvV4mdOSYeuxktF8zKlogaZ1OKmx1gcrOGx1B7tPitjZKgzWw5MLUo7HDzAbMPeew6GhLEHX1acC6lotcalllJxXizl1H+FJOEbh3djG822aPfZvTjmq5Sw4dNaaMT67ofy15-jPmLNqfAy+zTyWKuuqq+l8aUtE1XogQ+aLAjYu+baxG8rZyJOwcWWHL1XHSkNc888wrdGn0zY0-5sTh2gvHdCzViyfTUPS39bx9N9663cUMQx-b83nuVfndV07Tg1sodntWxrwzH2Wfu9ZjrUauu6ZC9J+N35I62V2DerbzWcOwcS5B0HYrFsQ+W-ob84sFxlqJ+Z129HhN7tEzSgtrGsf6ZW4TD6bnpajd+wVibRXWdWfZzZ9HRG0skb6zPMyv6mc7Za6T0rc2Atg6pw5yHCveh3MFzZW9CPaNZruyV2bj3Ocse6zz3rK3pByZiXKgZV2N1i9u8jy3D2OfMbs5j42b3TvSA4Uh1cl2xvXc9+b73nIydlYp1zu3Qfsc1aQ2ZLYZTpZ5ZF+N-7Am4t+b9512XS35crbFuak37uaM3dj9Nn3qPp0y6O8Rk1mUI5R3ZSrgHu3gdJa15TuduuaeZTmjNCJvfC-ZB4ntwfT3h-c9T7z2nyj8cR-rj9wlfGC+TZZxb+PGvrf+4x8FlfDvacR4lpliBwud9-eA6rg-cfhzH5L63l77ez1rjk3gnLxM0+++xWR+VuH+0GbecuHeE0q4Ye8OteTWzOIBb+YB0uEBX+UBP+JSnCruscQB2Gc+A+5OQ+yegegCwefW2Bc0vqP0+BXujeoBvuaBKWOuPWeuK2WwHCFGX2eUPGD+oue+4uh+KBTBaO6B4Oo+Fe+gM8sgX0oKl82+g6RKT+feauxezBC2I+bBY+YAM8YeS4+O9cA6Q6deMeSODBIhzeBG2uWh9u7B0hvQiaiGAGeBpu9e5h8WjBVhB2S+Ke5BaeYcZarKUSRu1k9+Shu+KhM+U2nhlhUuYhLBthF+9hOA00UsH0NeUeHugh9BsRgQCemui+pB5+-hq+qRC4qyQ2q6dBDeeRUABRJ+pekB5e0BaRHC5EF8l8NRHh6hCRmhy+pRl+qRiuFkuBxMxhyhymqhJOvRLe4hrBdhOhg2cmiGm+OefBERj+Ux0RL+Fh+R7+GhNhAx+SFB40g2iaWwK03RD8hBbO7WcxiRxxCypx0h3aGRhhOe1xgOrWRBieJBtuZBJxARVcVREsaRs84RJhiBz+yB+xqBfRRxfhQJZRuhS6H0t+XRbhZhD81Yz8sx1hvhgJzxwJZxXeZa8hrhCBiOqmdRdUohDx-RSJxJKJ00Xe9kCmNsqaWRphORtR+JPhxRr2JJ0h0cLmK01RWJvJPR8+xBRRAJJRyJQxuhJ80OABP0XJee0eUpNJ-JSe8pQpLJE+JShClJ3J0J0xsJ9RBxCJhJCpzJSp3aBuHK2e7mXx-edxIO-xAedpcGwpqRzm0cN6kJkxZmMJEuKO8RDJiJRJvpLJC0ZkS45ENs0SbpMRupXpZ+BpSpMSrKJ4NB30-4DwCwGg8wvgQAA)):

[image]